# Daily UILocalNotification firing more than once

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, uilocalnotification

Hello i am facing a weird kind problem. Actually i want to schedule a daily notification (only once a day) at 8:00 AM. Below is my code for scheduling daily notification.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [formatter dateFromString:@"08:00"];
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = date;
localNotification.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody = @"You just received a local notification";
localNotification.alertAction = @"View Details";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[formatter release];
[date release];
```

My problem is, I receive 2 local notifications. One at 8:00 AM and other at 10:00 AM. Why i am getting notification at 10:00 AM. I am scheduling it at 8:00 AM only. I know UILocalNotification library have some other weird kind of problems/bugs on most of apple devices. I just want to confirm whether there is some mistake in my code or it is a weird behaviour of UILocalNotification Library. I dont know why Apple is not working on resolving the issues being reported by many developers about UILocalNotification.

Note: I am using Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1

Comment: :Add am/pm in your date. That is your problem. [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"]; set your date format like this

Comment: Try to `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` before you schedule a local notification. And, your code is not good from the memory management point of view. Change your `NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [formatter dateFromString:@"08:00"];` lines to `NSDate *date =[formatter dateFromString:@"08:00"];`, and remove the `[date release];` line, and also don't forget to `release` you local notification object after scheduling it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the [BEST](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/) link to get your answer.

Comment: This would be best as a comment..not as an answer