# How to set Local notification at(morning 8:00AM and Evening 8:00PM) in ios?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Currently i am using Xcode 7.2

I have an requirement like: Actually i want to schedule a daily notification (only twice a day) at **8:00 AM & 8:00 PM.**

I am new to usage of Local notification. I did some R & D i found some links also like: [Daily UILocalNotification firing more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762936/daily-uilocalnotification-firing-more-than-once)
.  But i am unable to solve my issue....

If either the app is in **Inactive/Active/Background/Suspend** i need to show the Local notification to specific user.

How can i overcome this issue?

Comment: I have just answered a question like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126988/swift-ios-localnotifications/36127083#36127083

Comment: Hi @ Emil, I am developing an app like Health info (Doctor Recommended & Actual Values like (BP, Sugar, Heart Beat and etc..,)). I need to inform user daily at  8:00 AM & 8:00 PM. these intervals and user should re-enter those values

Comment: ThanQ @ khuong291. If you don't mine can you please post answer in Objective-c and in which method i have to call you're code.. My requirement is like: Inactive/Active/Background/Suspend  i need to display notification..

Comment: are you using swift or Obj-C?

Comment: Hi @ Lorenzo, I am using Objective-c

Answer (score 2):

**Notification For Morning 8:00 AM**

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif1.alertBody = @"Morning 8:00 AM";
NSDateComponents *components1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components1 setHour:8];
[components1 setMinute:0];
localNotif1.fireDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components1];
[localNotif1 setRepeatInterval:NSCalendarUnitDay];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif1];
```

**Notification For Evening 8:00 PM**

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif2.alertBody = @"Evening 8:00 PM";
NSDateComponents *components2 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components2 setHour:20];
[components2 setMinute:0];
localNotif2.fireDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components2];
[localNotif2 setRepeatInterval:NSCalendarUnitDay];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif2];
```

Comment: ThanQ @mital solanki, I am new to this Local notification concept. If you don't mine In which method(Delegate or other) i have to call these methods?. It should be work in Inactive/Active/Background/Suspend